# function without parameter as it behaves default whatever we put in it or not

Tags: jquery

This is the jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {

        alert( "Hi!" );

        event.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

within the function `event` is a parameter to which we could replace it with `whatever` and we could do as this `whatever.preventDefault()` but I would like to know without inserting any parameter like `function()` could we do only this `.preventDefault();` does this work?

Comment: Short answer: no, you cannot. `preventDefault()` is a method of an event, so if you don't capture the event in the anonymous function, then how would you use it's methods?

Comment: No, preventDefault() is Event object method.

Comment: if you want your 'a' not to navigate anywhere, just make it's href="#", then you won't need any .preventDefault();

Comment: Could you please show us your HTML code for this jquery block?

Comment: As my experience with JS/Jquery, this is not possible.

Comment: . is a binary operator so you need something to use it on. And it wouldn't make sense to do that anyway. It would be confusing to anyone looking at your code.

Comment: @Virus721 if so, could we use without a dot `preventDefault()`

Comment: preventDefault is a property of the object event, meaning that is only exist inside that event object and no in the scope where you're trying to call it. I absolutly have no idea why you would want to do that. It is as senseless as trying to call toString on nothing.

Comment: You would like to prevent default behaviour on a matched set of elements without specifying it inside handlers, is it?

Comment: @roasted yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

No, your code can't work if you don't specify a parameter to the function because a method can't be applied to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `preventDefault`() function is associated with the event.

so you should have

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function (event) {            
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

or

you can use `return false`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").click(function () {            
            return false;
        });
    });
```

`return false` from within a jQuery event handler is effectively the same as calling both `e.preventDefault` on the passed **jQuery.Event** object.

[Check this SO **Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/1671639)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do that. see below code:

```
 $( "a" ).click(function() {
      alert( "Hi!" );
 }).preventDefault(); //add .preventDefault() here
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event parameter is as a matter of fact jQuery [event data object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).
It represents state of the event along with its control points.

If you don't have this, you can't control what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can capturing event to, usefull to delegate event:

```
var eventToPrevent = "click",
    selectorToPrevent = "a";

document.addEventListener(eventToPrevent, function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(selectorToPrevent)) e.preventDefault();
}, true);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RaNvm/)

Comment: sorry! I didn't mean that.

Comment: See updated answer, i maybe mis understood what you are looking for